# Create little tabs over other containers and stuff

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a mini adventure game on a website and was wondering how I would make an overlaying tab for inventory (like organize/format it in html. Preferably using bootstrap 4 containers/columns/rows/etc, though not required)? See picture for what I mean.

(I am using bootstrap 4, if that helps)

[image: reference image]

What I'm looking for:
You can click to open an inventory and it pops over the Scene View. You can also close the inventory by either an X or by clicking the inventory button again. You can also have multiple inventories open if you want.

This is all of the code I have right now

```html
<div class="container-fluid h-100 w-100">
        <div class="row fixed-bottom">
            <div class="col-12 w-100">
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle w-100 justify-content-center" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary menubtn">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Inv1" autocomplete="off" checked> Inv
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-danger menubtn">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Inv2" autocomplete="off"> Inv
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-success menubtn">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Inv3" autocomplete="off"> Inv
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-secondary menubtn">
                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="Inv4" autocomplete="off"> Inv
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

This is what menubtn is for anybody curious

```css
.menubtn {width:25%;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with a combination of [dropup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#dropup) and [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/). No JS required.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv1">
            Inv 1
          </button>
          <div id="inv1" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv1" class="dropdown-header text-right">x</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv2">
            Inv 2
          </button>
          <div id="inv2" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv2" class="dropdown-header text-right">x</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv3">
            Inv 3
          </button>
          <div id="inv3" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv3" class="dropdown-header text-right">x</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="btn-group dropup">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv4">
            Inv 4
          </button>
          <div id="inv4" class="dropdown-menu">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inv4" class="dropdown-header text-right">x</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit this to include the other bits like <body> and such? When I try this code I just can't get it to work

Comment: @ItsOYo done, But if it doesn't work, you probably have some code messing with it.

Comment: This is what my code is, https://pastebin.com/eyubbi5J. And this is what happens on the site (https://i.gyazo.com/9ec361eab919613b3534b459059ab1ed.png). The buttons dont scale to the size of the page and they dont open up. EDIT: Removing the imported stuff doesnt change it.

Comment: @ItsOYo I used Bootstrap v4.3.1, you are using v4.0.0. May be that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript for this, toggling the menu's display between "none" and "block" when a button is clicked:

```js
function togglevisible(elem) {
  elem = document.getElementById(elem);
  if (elem.style.display == "none") {
    elem.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    elem.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 25%;
}

#button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="togglevisible('menu');">Click Me</button>
<div id="menu">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My question is how would I create a section (exactly like in the pic with the overlay) using bootstrap 4? I understand how to make something visible and invisible, but my issue is actually formatting/organizing it

Comment: I've never used bootstrap, so I don't know then

Answer (score 1):

If you're determined to use Bootstrap, you may want to take a look at the [dropup](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropup-variation) variation of the dropdown menu. It's likely not the most robust solution, but I thought it was a strangely interesting idea so I made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/extrachrisb/pen/BeXQRR) and used simple column classes for the sizing and a few tweaks with utility classes.

A lot of the styles will probably need to be overwritten, but that can be a big drawback any time you're using Bootstrap to build something custom.  Personally, I'd recommend just making something on your own, as the responsive grid layout is simple to implement with your own `col-md-*` classes with relative widths and a few media queries. It also gives you way more flexibility, unless there are other reasons you want to use Bootstrap. But that's just my own opinion.

Comment: Bootstrap is not required, but preferred